# Norm in finding local extrema for functional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, calculus-of-variations

In "The Calculus of Variations" by Bruce van Brunt, he says:

> Let $J:C^2[x_0,x_1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a functional of the form $$J(y)=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}f(x,y,y^\prime)dx,$$ where $f$ is a function assumed to have at least second-order continous partial derivatives with respect to $x,y$ and $y^\prime$. Given two values $y_0,y_1\in\mathbb{R}$, the fixed endpoint variational problem consists of determining the functions $y\in C^2[x_0,x_1]$ such that $y(x_0)=y_0$, $y(x_1)=y_1$, and $J$ has a local extremum in $S$ at $y\in S$. Here $$S=\{y\in C^2[x_0,x_1]\,:\,y(x_0)=y_0\mbox{ and }y(x_1)=y_1\}.$$
>
> (...) Suppose that $J$ has a local extremum in $S$ at $y$. For
>   definiteness, let  us assume that $J$ has a local maximum at $y$.
>   Then, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $J(\widehat{y})-J(y)\le 0$
>   for all $\widehat{y}\in S$ such that $\|\widehat{y}-y\|<\epsilon$.

However, he doesn't specify which is the norm $\|\cdot\|$. He continues saying:

> For any $\widehat{y}\in S$ there is an $\eta\in C^2[x_0,x_1]$, $\eta(x_0)=0=\eta(x_1)$, such that $\widehat{y}=y+\epsilon\eta$, and for $\epsilon$ small Taylor's theorem implies that $$f(x,\widehat{y},\widehat{y}^\prime)=f(x,y,y^\prime)+\epsilon\left\{\eta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\eta^\prime\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^\prime}\right\}+O(\epsilon^3).$$
>
> Thus
>   $$J(\widehat{y})-J(y)=\epsilon\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\left(\eta\frac{\partial
>  f}{\partial y}+\eta^\prime\frac{\partial f}{\partial
>  y^\prime}\right)dx+O(\epsilon^3)$$

By the last, I suppose that this norm is a type of "sup norm", but I don't know.

Can you helpme to deduce which is the norm used? That is, which is the norm from which he is defining the local maximum?

Comment: it is true for any norm on $C^2([x_0,x_1])$, for example $\displaystyle \|y-\hat{y}\|^2 = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} |y(x)-\hat{y}(x)|^2 dx$, but the problem [suggests to consider the norm  in the Sobolev space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Functions_vanishing_at_the_boundary) $H_0^1([x_0,x_1])$ as $\{ \hat{y} \in S \ | \ \|y-\hat{y}\| < \epsilon \}$ is an $\epsilon$ ball in $ H_0^1([x_0,x_1])$

Comment: @user1952009: I don't have the book at hand, but at this early stage there should be no need for Sobolev norms.

Comment: this is implicit as I wrote